# Trazer dados mensal via php + mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tenho um grafico chart que irá trazer as vendas mensais do ano passado.
Estou conseguindo trazer os dados do banco e esta listando mensalmebte, porem quando tenho 2 registros do mesmo mes ele não soma, insere do lado e exclui o ultimo. Por exemplo
Se eu tenho 2 vendas no mes de janeiro, ele lista a primeira em janeiro a segunda em fevereiro e nao lista a venda de dezembro. O que estou tentando fazer é somar as vendas do mes e listar em seu respectivo mes.

Esse é meu JS:

```html
 $('document').ready(function (){

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "chart-vendas-ano.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {

//     // for (var i in data){
//     //   console.log(data[i].total)
var vendasarray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      vendasarray.push(data[i].total);
    }
grafico(vendasarray);
  }
});
})

    function grafico(vendas){

var ctx2 = document.getElementById('chart-line').getContext("2d");

var gradientStroke1 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

gradientStroke1.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(203,12,159,0.2)');
gradientStroke1.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
gradientStroke1.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(203,12,159,0)'); //purple colors

var gradientStroke2 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

gradientStroke2.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(20,23,39,0.2)');
gradientStroke2.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
gradientStroke2.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(20,23,39,0)'); //purple colors

new Chart(ctx2, {
type: "line",
data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
    datasets: [{
            label: "Vendas 2020",
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#cb0c9f",
            borderWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: gradientStroke1,
            fill: true,
            data: vendas,
            maxBarThickness: 6
```

Esse é meu PHP:

```html
<?php
include_once("../../conexao.php");

$ano_passado = $pdo->query("SELECT total from vendas where year(data) = (year(now())-1)order by month(data)");

while($results = $ano_passado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $result[] = $results;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: *"porem quando tenho 2 registros do mesmo mes ele não soma, insere do lado e exclui o ultimo"* se o seu problema é com os dados, inclua na pergunta um exemplo dos registros do banco e como retorna a query. *"O que estou tentando fazer é somar as vendas do mes e listar em seu respectivo mes"* não vi no seu código nada relacionado a "somar", nem na query nem no código, isso não ficou claro, explique melhor onde ou de que forma está tentando fazer isso

Answer (score 0):

Você faz um consulta da coluna total onde ano seja igual a ano -1.
O SQL te retorna vários valores ao que tudo indica deveria ser 12 resultados ordenados por mês.

Mas pode existir mais de um registro total no mesmo mês, então você mais de 12 registros.

Inicialmente sua consulta deve conter a coluna da data do registro e o valor.
Outro ponto é você precisa somar e agrupar (`group by` [MySQL GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)) seus dados por mês conforme mencionou.

Logo sua consulta deveria ser algo do tipo, selecione os dados do ano passado agrupando por mês o somando o agrupamento pela colina total:

```
select month(data), sum(total) as total 
from tabela where year = (year(now())-1) 
group by month(data)
order by month(data)
```

Veja que assim você já receberá os dados agrupados por mês e somados no caso da existência de mais de uma ocorrência no agrupamento.

Um outro exemplo, dados do mês passado agrupados por dia:

```
select day(data), sum(total) as total 
from tabela group where month = (month(now())-1)  
group by day(data) 
order by day(data)
```

Um outro exemplo agrupado por ano:

```
select year(data), sum(total) as total 
from tabela group by year(data) 
order by year(data)
```